# How do I ensure that the text entered into a UIAlertview transforms the text of a UIButton and STAYS that way after exiting and reentering the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, constraints, nsuserdefaults

TL;DR : Open iOS app
Enter a promo code
Close app
Open app
Actual Results: 
Promo code box is out of wack (see images)
Expected Results:
Promo code should still be displayed

So I've got a UIButton whose text keeps changing after the user clicks on it and exits and reruns the app. So here's what the area looks like before the change:

[image]

Then, after the user clicks on the button, they're prompted with a UIAlertview
[image]

Finally, after the user has entered their promo code, they return the the viewcontroller, and the UIButton, after adopting the name of the promo code, completely changes size, font, and text. That's the intended goal. The problem is that when I close the app and rerun it in the simulator, a different message appears, rather than the original promo code entered. [image][image]

I can add more code/explanation upon request. Thank you in advance for the help.

EDIT: Here's what the button looks like in storyboard:

[image]

NSUserdefaults code:

```
- (BOOL)hasStoredPromotionCode {
    NSData *data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"userPromotion"];
    self.promotion = (PNGPromotionModel *)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];

    if (self.promotion) {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: What kind of constraints do you add to the button, it seems like the button uses intrinsicContentSize.

Comment: Constraints are added via Storyboard.

Comment: Ok, make sure that button has some width and height. Add constraints for width and height, such that the button size remain static.

Comment: I did add constraints for the width and height but the button changes anyways.

Comment: Ok, then there seems to be something wrong with it. Does xcode throw any autolayout breakage error in console ?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. Also, I'll update my question with how the button actually looks in storyboard.

Comment: Edited above w/more info

Comment: You are saving the string you want for the promo code in NSUserDefaults, synchronizing the defaults, then reading the value back when you restart - right?

Comment: No I don't think so! When I check the content of the promotions object in the code after restarting the app, I'm getting a nil back. (I put the code up top). If I'm doing it incorrectly mind explaining how I'd go about that?

Comment: can you take a screenshot of the constraints you have on the button? from the size inspector please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up being the actual problem was the fact that I wasn't using UIControlStateSelected. A foolish error. But that was the actual issue. Even after synchronizing my defaults and making sure the success block was returning the data properly, and that I was then accessing that data properly, the button still experienced issues.

The following code is what ultimately fixed it:

```
 [self.promoCodeButton setTitle:buttonTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal & UIControlStateHighlighted & UIControlStateSelected];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to retrieve your value from NSUserDefaults it means that it's not getting stored properly.

I'm not sure how you are using your object but make sure you are storing correctly in user defaults.

```
- (void)storeInDefaults:(MyObject*)object {
   NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   [defaults setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:object] forKey:@"userPromotion"];
   [defaults synchronize];
}
```

When you use NSKeyedArchiver with custom objects you also have to make sure your object adhere's to the NSCoding protocol by implementing `initWithCoder:` and `encodeWithCoder`. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/index.html